# PHP CLI Callback

Tags: php

When PHP run normally I just refresh the browser via PHP header, javascript to re-run.

But I want do something like this in CLI mode. My current crawling script took very long time to execute and may be over script timeout.

Then want to callback the script again and make it work itselft ?

Comment: May I ask *why* you want to do this?

Comment: I write a crawling script and it's took very long time. Then i want call this script again after it's crawling finish a page

Comment: *"not work"* does not qualify for a question. Post your code. Tell what exactly did turn out and what was wanted instead. Ensure you've got error logging enabled.

Comment: Hi hakre. I just edit my question and remove anything doesn't related this question. About the code, it's very hard to bring all the source to here. But I can give something simplest like this `<?php echo 'test'; exec('php test.php');?>`. You can try this, i cann't get any output by running the code via CLI mode.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do this would be to use

```
require($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

However I really can't understand why you'd want to do it...

Comment: Thank Aleks. It's work. But I wondering may be it's can re-declare my old function and overwrite my variable

Comment: About the reason i want to do this. I write a crawling script and i want to make it work itself. I cann't excute it in a same time because it's took very long time. And i don't want turn on browser and waiting it refresh. Then i hope i can make it on CLI mode. Thanks Aleks

Comment: @TranMinhDung If you have function definitions, then you'll need to write it in a smarter way, checking whether the function is defined before defining it.  Have a look at [function_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) function.

Comment: I think using `require` still in same script connection, may be it can timeout in a long execute. I think it's will better if i can call it like a new.

Comment: @TranMinhDung Using `exec` can still work: you're executing `php` with parameter `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`

Comment: I've use `exec` before. But unfortunately i'm not success. May be callback success, but i cann't catch any output when i call `exec` in a php script. I make a small test `<?php exec('php test2.php');?>` save as `test.php` and `<?php echo 'test';?>` save as `test2.php`. Then run `php test.php`, i got blank output

Comment: @TranMinhDung Are you passing the second parameter to the `exec` call?  Read [`exec` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) documentation carefully.

Comment: Thank Aleks G. I'll try with this but i still want looking more solutions for performing and real way to close each of connection. Not looping itselft inside like this